# Serializing and saving/loading R6 classes

Tags: r, serialization, json-deserialization, r6

Im looking for a way to save an R6 class to disk, particularly saving all the fields into disk, maybe as JSON and then loading them back into an R6 instance.

The constraint through is that i want to implement it in the parent R6 Class and is inherited by all the children classes thus the method cannot hardcode of what these fields are as they might vary from one child class to the other.

Is there a way to do this efficiently and quickly?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is there a reason why `saveRDS()` won't work for you?

Comment: @Limey , because i want to save only the non-functions part of the class to save on space from one side, and on the other side, JSON format would be easier to transfer to the web interface which is needed. However, im working now on a solution that seems to be fairly easy and generic, i will share it in a bit